# Prism Xamarin Forms Navigation service, DependencyService

Tags: dependency-injection, xamarin.forms, prism

As Prism said,

> To obtain the INavigationService in your ViewModels simply ask for it
>   as a constructor parameter

https://prismlibrary.github.io/docs/xamarin-forms/Navigation-Service.html#getting-the-navigation-service

like this:

```
public SpeakPageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService) : base(navigationService)

{

_navigationService = navigationService;

}
```

and I want to use ITextToSpeech interface as Prism sample :

```
public MainPageViewModel(ITextToSpeech textToSpeech)
{
    _textToSpeech = textToSpeech;
    SpeakCommand = new DelegateCommand(Speak);
}
```

https://prismlibrary.github.io/docs/xamarin-forms/Dependency-Service.html#use-the-service

**The problem is**: when add another parameter to the constructor, the navigation doesn't work.

```
public SpeakPageViewModel(ITextToSpeech textToSpeech, INavigationService navigationService) : base(navigationService)
        {
            _navigationService = navigationService;
            _textToSpeech = textToSpeech;
        }
```

project file : http://www.mediafire.com/file/nl6dx5c4mc3mg63/FirstPrismApp.rar

Comment: Did you try putting the `navigationService` as the first parameter? Hopefully that shouldn't matter, but since the naming requirement is there as well..

Comment: @GeraldVersluis yes I did. No difference. Not work

Comment: Which container are you using? Can you include a repo app that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: @DanS. I've added the project file link

Comment: @DanS. I've tested both DryIco and Unity and still have the problem. It's  so strange to me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prism 7 changed this behavior as it is actually an anti-pattern to rely on a secondary container. You simply need to register your TextToSpeech service in the `IPlatformInitializer` like:

```
public class iOSInitializer : IPlatformInitializer
{
    public void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
    {
        containerRegistry.Register<ITextToSpeech, TextToSpeech_iOS>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Dan.S, please answer these two question: 1- if add an int argument or any type of variable or object to the MainPageViewmodel constructor derived from ViewModelBase, it raises an error too. How can I register a variable?! why unity do like that?!
2- Where can I learn Prism well?

Comment: You cannot pass primitive values directly into the constructor of a ViewModel unless you have added a specific registration with the container for that ViewModel type. I cannot help you much beyond that as it becomes very container specific and well outside of the bounds of this question. As for where to learn. There are of course the samples on GitHub. A lot of dev's have benefited from the Prism Slack Channel which you can join by becoming a Prism Patron. Beyond that you could hire a consultant like myself to help jumpstart your team.