# Resolution of the dependency - Xamarin - Unity

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, xamarin.forms, unity-container

The project is a copy of [Unity doc](http://prismlibrary.github.io/docs/xamarin-forms/Dependency-Service.html) but it raise an error that I cant underestand

The error is:

> Unhandled Exception:
>
> Unity.Exceptions.ResolutionFailedException: Resolution of the
>   dependency failed, type = 'System.Object', name = 'MainPage'.
>   Exception occurred while: Calling constructor
>   SecondPrims.Views.MainPage(). Exception is: ResolutionFailedException
>   - Resolution of the dependency failed, type = 'SecondPrims.ViewModels.MainPageViewModel', name = '(none)'. Exception
>   occurred while: while resolving. Exception is:
>   InvalidOperationException - The current type, ITextToSpeech, is an
>   interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?
>   ----------------------------------------------- At the time of the exception, the container was:    Resolving
>   SecondPrims.ViewModels.MainPageViewModel,(none)   Resolving parameter
>   'textToSpeech' of constructor
>   SecondPrims.ViewModels.MainPageViewModel(ITextToSpeech textToSpeech)
>       Resolving ITextToSpeech,(none)
>
> ----------------------------------------------- At the time of the exception, the container was:    Resolving
>   SecondPrims.Views.MainPage,MainPage (mapped from System.Object,
>   MainPage)
>       Resolving SecondPrims.Views.MainPage,MainPage
>       Calling constructor SecondPrims.Views.MainPage()  occurred

Project file:
http://www.mediafire.com/file/fs656jowkiy2bd9/SecondPrims.zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is because of registering the ITextToSpeech Interface in each platform.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/50493741/478162

> Prism 7 changed this behavior as it is actually an anti-pattern to
>   rely on a secondary container. You simply need to register your
>   TextToSpeech service in the IPlatformInitializer like:

```
public class iOSInitializer : IPlatformInitializer
{
    public void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
    {
        containerRegistry.Register<ITextToSpeech, TextToSpeech_iOS>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you adding your dependencies correctly ?

```
containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<MainPage>();
containerRegistry.Register<ITextToSpeech, TextToSpeech>();
```

Comment: What is TextToSpeech, I don't have any class named it

Comment: @Behzad you do, look at your error "Resolving ITextToSpeech,(none)", Its in your MainPageViewModel

Comment: That's a parameter of MainPageViewModel constructor. I've found the answer and will answer my question. Thank you for attention.